# How to make a flipbook from a pdf

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a lot of pdfs and i need to convert each one of them into a flipbook so people can choose one and read it. I can't find a way to do this that is free. So i wonder if there's a way for me to make only with html, css and javascript.

Answer (score 3):

Look at any pdf viewer and that ability is not generally available, What you will find in any flipbook is a viewer like Mozilla PDF.js which replaces the pdf with images.
So the simplest answer is use any conversion lib like https://3dflipbook.net/ or https://dearflip.com/responsive-html5-flipbook-jquery-plugin/

or any one of the 899 here https://github.com/search?q=flipbook
this one looks nice https://kubil-ismail.github.io/Pdf-Flipbook/
or what about https://notshriram.github.io/React-Flipbook-Demo/